# Azure DevOps Extension get position of executing Task in Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to analyze the log of the [Ansible](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/Ansible/Src/Tasks/Ansible) task inside a release pipeline with a custom *task extension* (node). In generell this is no big thing, but I ask my self whether it is possible to get the position of my executing task inside the pipeline?

#### Usecase

The **user** could add an `Ansible` task and if he want he can add my custom task to analyze the log (and publish somewhere). To decide which `Ansible` task inside the release pipeline should analyzed, the **user** should but the *custom task* directly after the `Ansible` task.

Something like this:

```
Release Pipeline 1.) Stage:
- Initialize job
- Download artifacts
- CopyFilesOverSSH
- Ansible <--- this should analyzed
- Custom Task 
- Ansible
- Finialize job
```

#### Szenario

A release Pipeline with 3 Stages.

- 1.) Stage linear
- 2.) Stage & 3.) Stage parallel on second level
- all stages contains a ansible task
- all stages should contain my custom *task extension* to analyze the ansible task log

#### The Problem

When I now request the [Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) REST call I can loop though all environments, all jobs, all tasks looks like:

```
    let release: Release = await Api.getRelease(Env.System.TeamProject, Env.Release.ReleaseId);

    // loop environments (stages)
    for (let environment of release.environments) {
      // loop deploy steps
      for (let deployStep of environment.deploySteps || []) {
        // loop phases
        for (let releaseDeployPhase of deployStep.releaseDeployPhases || []) {
          // loop jobs
          for (let deploymentJob of releaseDeployPhase.deploymentJobs || []) {
            let ansible: ReleaseTask[] = [];
            // loop tasks
            for (let task of deploymentJob.tasks || []) {
              if (task.startTime && task.finishTime) {
                if (task.name === "Ansible") ansible.push(task);
              }
            }
            console.log(ansible);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

on runtime on this state my executing *custom task* is not finished yet (`TaskStatus.InProgress`), so together with the id of my task I am should able to detect the position inside the pipeline.

#### Some better Solution?

But I hope there is a much better solution, I mean the task should know which position it has inside the pipeline or? Maybe there is an information you can get over the [azure-pipelines-task-lib/task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md) lib?

Something like:

```
task.getRank() >>> 3
task.getEnvironment >>> 2
```

What also could help is when you could request the task name and the id inside the task program. Currently I have to create own variables with these information.

Something like this:

```
me.Id() >>> "8bb50e0a-8efb-47a4-b12a-2190f3a4d16a"
me.Name() >>> "MyCustomTask"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could analyze the log of the Ansible task via power shell and REST API, an example is shown below:

```
  $listurl="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/releases/{Release id}?api-version=6.1-preview.8"
    $PAT="{PAT}"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get
    
$result.environments.deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks.name
    
    foreach($deploySteps in $result.environments.deploySteps)
    {
        write-host $deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks.name
        foreach($Task in $deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks){
            if($Task.name -eq "{analyze task display name}")
            {
                #write-host $Task.logUrl
                $TaskLogURL = $Task.logUrl
            }
        }
    }
    #write-host $TaskLogURL
    $TaskLog = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TaskLogURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get
    
    write-host $TaskLog
```

Comment: Hey Vito looks good, but honestly this do not answer the question (maybe I make my point not clear). **The question was:** is there an API to get the position inside a pipeline at runtime for a node task extension? Is there also an API to get the `ID` or `NAME` of a node task extension at runtime (inside the extension code). I have already approach similar to yours, but is there an official API like [azure-pipelines-task-lib/task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md)